# How to push an element to an array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, list

Let's say I have an array like:

```
{1,2,3}
```

So, for example, some function like:

```
arr.push(4);
```

Will make this array:

```
{4,1,2,3}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: What type is the  array `std::vector`? Or are you implementing your own code because of a school assignment that restricts what parts of c++ you can use?

Comment: ***How do I do that?*** Your question would be much better if you added a minimal example. [mcve]

Comment: In C++, `{1,2,3}` is not an array (it's a braced-init-list, usable to [list initialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) more than just arrays). Please provide more context so we can compensate for your inaccurate terminology.

Comment: You will need to write code that maintains the index of the end of the array, if the index is not past the end of the array, then write the value to the array at the index; otherwise, you'll have to reallocate the array.  This assumes you are pushing to the back or end of the array.

Comment: To push to the front of an array, first verify there is enough room for all the elements.  You may have to reallocate a larger array.  Move all the elements "down" by one element.  Write your new value to position 0.  Increment the size of the array (quantity of elements in the array), as arrays don't retain their capacity or size.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to push an element to an array. The size of an array remains the same through the lifetime of the array.

What can be done instead is to create a new, larger array and copy the elements from the old array. Such dynamic growable "array" data structure is provided for you in the standard library: `std::vector`.